# no EC as Azure Payment method found

Tags: azure

i wanted to buy some Azure Products online, but i found out that i couldn't choose EC (Electronic Cash - usual payment method in Germany) as a payment method, only Master Card and Visa (tried it on the German version of the site aswell).
so my question is: Is it possible to do so ? or is it defenitely not.

the reason i need reassurence is because if it's not possible i am gonna have to approach my Boss about it (and it would be extremely dumb if it turned out to be Possible).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This is not a development question and might have been better suited for the MSDN forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can do invoices and different payment methods. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/invoicing/

Comment: Didn't answer my question, but still helpfull

Comment: Sorry, I meant that to come across as you should contact them via that link and they could give you all the options.